# vector iterator not dereferencable C++

Tags: c++, function, 2d-vector

I'm trying to set the value of a float by using (max_element-min_element) from a vector. I'm looping over several of these, hence the vector of floats and vector of vectors.

I'm getting the following error:

`Expression:  Vector iterator not dereferencable`

```
vector<float> amplitudeStorage;
vector<vector<float>> vectorStorage;    


 int main(){

       for (int i = 0; i < amplitudeStorage.size(); i++) 
       {
        AssignWaveAmplitude(amplitudeStorage[i], vectorStorage[i]);
       }
  }
```

It happens on the function call. The function looks like this:

```
void AssignWaveAmplitude(float amplitudeVariable, vector<float> dataVectorr) 
{
    amplitudeVariable = (*max_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr))) - (*min_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr)));
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks very much.

EDIT1:The solution to this problem is the first comment to this question. Some of the vectors I was using were empty, which caused the error.

EDIT2:

@WhozCraig so now I've done this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amplitudeStorage.size(); i++) {
    amplitudeStorage[i] =AssignWaveAmplitude(vectorStorage[i]);                                   
    }
```

and this:

```
float AssignWaveAmplitude( vector<float> dataVectorr) {

    return (*max_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr))) - (*min_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr)));
}
```

but the floats all still come out to the same number. any idea why?

EDIT3: It turns out the reason as to why the floats were coming out wrong was because I was outputting them wrong.

I was doing:
 `cout << lowerBackYAmplitude<< endl` 
(this was one of the values in amplitudeStorage)

I should have been doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amplitudeStorage.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout << amplitudeStorage[i] << endl;
                }
```

Comment: Here's a thought. break that otherwise exorbitant single line into pieces and see which *one* of those trips you're dereferencing an end-iterator. My guess, `dataVector` is empty. Of course, without an MCVE, that's prolly all you're gonna get.

Comment: @WhozCraig yep just checked over the code and some of the vectors that were stored in vectorStorage were empty. No errors now, but `amplitudeVariable` always comes out as `-1.07374e+08` now. any idea why?

Comment: LOL. not a clue, Failure to initialize something? But at least you know why that invalid dereference was surfacing.  Glad you found *that*. Btw, maybe give the copy-buffers on your rig a break and pass that vector by `const` reference rather than by value-copy. Just saying... =P Best of luck.

Comment: Duh. `float amplitudeVariable` is passed by value, you need to either pass it by reference or don't pass it at all and just use the return value of the function for your result value. As written, your not modifying the value back on the caller side in `amplitudeStorage[i]` at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig: while your comment is correct, there's really not need for the "Duh".

Comment: Please modify the question to provide a single, self-contained, minimal example which demonstrates your problem.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JamesYoungman the "Duh" was directed at *me* for not seeing it, while simultaneously commenting on passing the *second* param (the vector) by const ref.

Comment: @WhozCraig so now I've done this:
`for (int i = 0; i < amplitudeStorage.size(); i++) {
      amplitudeStorage[i] = AssignWaveAmplitude(vectorStorage[i]);
     }`

and this:

`float AssignWaveAmplitude( vector<float> dataVectorr) {
 
 return (*max_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr))) - (*min_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr)));
}`

But the floats are all still the same number. any idea why?

Comment: @WhozCraig I've made your changes and added them to the bottom of the question, but all the floats still come out as `-1.07374e+08` , even though when I debug it and watch `amplitudeVariable`, it does get set to the right numbers.

Any idea why?

Comment: Nope, but it's definitely a different question than the one originally posted.

Comment: Put this before the loop: `amplitudeStorage.reserve(vectorStorage.size())`

Comment: turns out the amplitudeStorage was storing the floats correctly. Instead of calling: `cout << lowerBackYAmplitude<< endl` (this was one of the values in `amplitudeStorage`) I did a loop around `amplitudeStorage` and outputted the values like so `cout << `amplitudeStorage[i]` << endl. Thank you both so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the vectors I was using were empty, which caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is probably trying to warn you that you cannot correctly refer to amplitudeStorage[i] for any value of i, when the amplitudeStorage vector is simply empty.   Either resize amplitudeStorage to match the size of vectorStorage at at the start, or use `push_back`.  I prefer `push_back`.  Here's a complete example (which also avoids passing vectors by value and corrects the problem in your code of using `int` to index a data structure whose size itself can grow to more than the maximum value an `int` can hold).

Note that this code is in C++11, since it uses a range-based for loop.  You may need to tell your compiler to turn on support for C++11.  There are lots of nice conveniences in C++11.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

float WaveAmplitude(const vector<float>& dataVectorr) {
  return (*max_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr)))
    - (*min_element(begin(dataVectorr), end(dataVectorr)));
}

vector<float> amplitudeStorage;
vector<vector<float>> vectorStorage;    

int main(void) {
  // Populate vectorStorage somehow here, replacing this comment.
  amplitudeStorage.clear();
  for (const auto& wave : vectorStorage)
    {
      amplitudeStorage.push_back(WaveAmplitude(wave));
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See full worked example. I try co compile and there is no problems.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<float> amplitudeStorage;
vector< vector<float> > vectorStorage;

void AssignWaveAmplitude(float& amplitudeVariable, const vector<float>& dataVectorr) {
    if( dataVectorr.size() ) {
        amplitudeVariable = 0;
        return;
    }
    amplitudeVariable = (*max_element(dataVectorr.begin(), dataVectorr.end())) - 
       (*min_element(dataVectorr.begin(), dataVectorr.end()));
}

main(){

    for (int i = 0; i < amplitudeStorage.size(); i++) {
        AssignWaveAmplitude(amplitudeStorage[i], vectorStorage[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I think you'll find std::begin is perfectly valid: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin Works with arrays too!

Comment: Yes I found but not fix answer yet

Comment: @fl-web with your answer i still get the same error.

Comment: It seems inefficient to pass the vector<float> by value.  Use a const reference!

Comment: What is reason to devote? I have compile this examplein gcc 4.6.2 and Visual Studio 2010 And there is no errors. Possible you are not show enough info about problem and enough code. Or your compiler have bug or currupt.

Comment: Yes to pass the vector it is absolutely not inefficient and need to use a const reference. But it is as in original question. And example is worked.

Comment: @J.Stopher check that vector dataVectorr is not empty, and return special value, or raise error for that case.

Comment: Try adding an element to vectorStorage before the loop.   Oops.  For this version of the code you should probably also do `amplitudeStorage.reserve(vectorStorage.size())`.  Also AssignWaveAmplitude in your code doesn't actually assign anything to the relevant entry in amplitudeStorage, because that is passed by value.

Comment: Yes thi is really useful comment.

Comment: Generally it is better to return a value from a function instead of passing a non-const reference.  Except when the object is very large.

Comment: I think that for cases with no tuple in return and with no exceptions better use result as succes status.